Windows Search on Windows 11, error 1630 data of this type is not supported
I'm having a hard time with the windows 11 search services, it won't start and it gives me the following error
Error 1630: Data of this type is not supported.

Indexing options also not running due to the search services isn't running

I tried system restore, and scan for corrupted system files and it's not working.
I rolled back the Windows update also.
it's driving me crazy, I appreciate the help.
Many Thanks

You might try downloading the Windows 11 ISO and reinstall, keeping all files.

I tried it, it didn't work unfortunately

The problem was fixed after deleting the files in the following path:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data
The service now starts without errors.
